# iOS use"Method Swizzling" reports an error

Tags: ios

Under MRC, "Method Swizzling" was used to exchange system method RETAIN. If no other code is added in the new method, the error will not be reported. I added NSLog and the error will be reported

Is the Runtime symbol binding changing the implementation of a retained method?

```
     #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface NSObject (whenRetained)
- (void)swizzle;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END


#import "NSObject+whenRetained.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>
@implementation NSObject (whenRetained)
- (void)swizzle {
   // NSLog(@"123"); // The program wouldn't crash without it
    [self swizzle];
//    NSLog(@"123");    //The program wouldn't crash without it
}
+ (void)load {
    Class class = [self class];
          
          SEL originalSelector = @selector(release);
          SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(swizzle);
         
          Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
          Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);
    BOOL didAddMethod = class_addMethod(class,
                                          originalSelector,
                                          method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                                          method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));
      if (didAddMethod) {
          
          class_replaceMethod(class,
                              swizzledSelector,
                              method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                              method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
      } else {
         
          method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
      }
}
@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
   [obj release];
}
```

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6o0x.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSMyw.png)

Comment: please post code, not images

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should add the involved code text instead of posting screen shots.

To your question: Your code is illegal, no matter if you add `NSLog` or not to the `swizzle` implementation.

The problem is that you call `swizzle` twice, this will lead to a double call to `release`, so your object gets overreleased hence your program crashes.

If this crash only appears when you add extra code to your `swizzle` implementation, this is just some coincidence.

Comment: You can ignore figure 3, which is a deliberate call to test whether the method exchange was successful after I removed NSLog from the new method

Comment: The code you changed does not crash. It crashes, if you (as in picture 3) call `swizzle` twice on the same object.

Comment: I updated the running screenshot.
I compiled objc-779.1, and I think the problem is in the fixupMessageRef method in runtime-new.
It changes the IMP of the retain method to objc_release.

Comment: So what is "objc-779.1"? Are we talking about the standard Xcode / iOS development in Objective C 2.0?